# What do we know about moduli spaces of sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, moduli-space

I want to know some examples of moduli schemes of (geometrically) stable sheaves over a higher dimensional base scheme.

The simpliest base schemes are the projective spaces $\mathbb{P}^n$ for $n\geq2$. However, I fail to find relevant research.

I want to know what are the moduli spaces of sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Have people figured them out clearly or are they still mysteries?

Comment: Does it form a stack? Naively, it seems too big to have any nice properties.

Comment: @KentaS There are moduli stacks of stable sheaves and moduli stacks of semistable sheaves. The moduli stack of stable sheaves has a coarse moduli scheme, which is often referred to as the *moduli scheme of stable sheaves*. However, the moduli scheme of semistable sheaves is not the coarse moduli space associated to the stack.

Comment: $n=2$ case is well studied. Look up papers of Maruyama.

Comment: For $n=2$ also Bertram, Coskun, Huizenga, and their collaborators (and of course the foundational work of Drezet and Le Potier). For $n=3$ I think Benjamin Schmidt did some work.